# Math related C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  float a;
  printf("Enter Real Number: ");
  scanf("%f", &a);
  int b;
  b=a*0.393701/12;
  float c;
  c=a*0.393701%12;
  printf("b, c");
  return 0;
}
```

Gives the error

```
10|error: invalid operands of types 'float' and 'double(double, double)' to binary 'operator*'|
10|error: expected ';' before 'of'|
```

Can someone point out the error please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the modulo operator `%` only on integer types (`char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, etc).

Also, you probably want to change `printf("b, c")` to `printf("%d, %f",b,c)`.

Comment: Do not forget [`fmod (...)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fmod/). There may be no operator to do this in C++ (the operator ***is*** defined for floating-point types in Java), but it has been part of the standard library since C.

Answer (score 0):

the modulus operator does not operate on float

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out modulo of two floating point numbers then use `fmod(real_number,real_number);`

example:-

```
fmod(5.5,1.3);
```

output : 0.300000